# What Quantitative Evaluation Methods Should Be Used for Robotics Simulation Research?

Tags: simulation, robotics

### Research on Photorealistic 3D Virtual Environments for Robotics

#### Background

I am engaged in a **robotics research project** focusing on the development and evaluation of **photorealistic 3D virtual environments**. Our approach integrates **Neural Radiance Fields (NeRF)** with **Unreal Engine 5 (UE5)** to create realistic environments for robot manipulation and navigation. The goal is to bridge the gap between simulated training and real-world application in robotics.

#### Main Contributions

1. **NeRF Scene Representations**: Using NeRF for rendering and static geometry, learned from indoor scene videos, to create realistic robot simulation environments.
2. **Photorealistic 3D Virtual Environments**: Demonstrating a faster method for creating these environments of real-world interiors than previous studies.
3. **Visual Guidance Control Policy**: Establishing that our policy has sufficient fidelity for effective simulation-reality transfer.

#### Current Stage

We are now ready to conduct **quantitative evaluations** to validate our approach and findings.

#### Questions

1. **Evaluation Techniques**: What are the appropriate quantitative evaluation techniques that can be applied to measure and compare the fidelity and accuracy of our 3D environments against real-world environments?
2. **Efficacy of Simulation-Reality Transfer**: How can we assess the effectiveness of the simulation-reality transfer of visually guided control policies?

Any insights, suggestions, or references to similar studies would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance.

Best regards,